# Two groupboxes in dockpanel, how to set resizing (strech & fixed) correctly?

Tags: wpf, groupbox, dockpanel

I have a very basic layout, but still not able to get the behaviour I want. Stupid me...

My grid has two columns, dynamic sized column left and fixed sized column right. This is working. Inside the right column I have stackpanel containing two buttons, they follow the window resizing correctly.

Inside the left column I have dockpanel containing two groupboxes, the lower has fixed height and is docked to the bottom. This groupbox follows the window resizing correctly, just like I want.

But I'm not able to get the upper groupbox to fill the upper section of the dockpanel. I can only set its height as fixed or when setting it "Auto" it gets strange height of 23...? I want it to fill the area and follow window resizing. I tried using stackpanel also in this column, but no success.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    
    <DockPanel x:Name="GroupPanel"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <GroupBox x:Name="AlarmGroup" Header="Alarms" Margin="10"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <GroupBox x:Name="LogGroup" Header="Log" Height="188" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </DockPanel>
    
    <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel" Width="190" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button x:Name="StartButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="150" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,10,0">Start</Button>
        <Button x:Name="StopButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="150" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,10,0">Stop</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `DockPanel` fills its remaining space with its last child.

You've set the `AlarmGroup` `GroupBox` as the first child, so it takes up only the space it needs; it's [default](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/combobox/itemheight). The second child has a fixed height, so it does not take up the remainder of the space.

To achieve the layout you are looking for, move `LogGroup` to be the first child of `GroupPanel` and set its `DockPanel.Dock` property to `Bottom`.

**Example**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <DockPanel x:Name="GroupPanel">
        <GroupBox x:Name="LogGroup" Header="Log"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                  Height="188" Margin="10"/>                
        <GroupBox x:Name="AlarmGroup" Header="Alarms" 
                  DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                  Margin="10"/>
    </DockPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel" 
                Width="190" 
                Grid.Column="1">    
        <Button x:Name="StartButton" 
                Width="150" Height="40" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0,20,10,0">Start</Button>
        <Button x:Name="StopButton" 
                Width="150" Height="40" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Margin="0,10,10,0">Stop</Button>    
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Result**

[image: Wpf application]

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you ?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DockPanel x:Name="GroupPanel"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        
        <GroupBox x:Name="LogGroup" Header="Log" Height="188" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <GroupBox x:Name="AlarmGroup" Header="Alarms" Margin="10"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    </DockPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel" Width="190" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button x:Name="StartButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="150" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,10,0">Start</Button>
        <Button x:Name="StopButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="150" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,10,0">Stop</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

In a DockPanel there is a property LastChildFill set to true by default which means that the last coltrol you put will take all the space. I also changed VerticalAligment="Bottom" to DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the screen size, Log and Alarm screens get smaller equally. I tried to do it by dividing it into partitions in a Grid. Is it enough for you ?

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="GroupPanel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <GroupBox x:Name="LogGroup" Header="Log" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
            <GroupBox x:Name="AlarmGroup" Header="Alarms" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel" 
            Width="190" 
            Grid.Column="1">
            <Button x:Name="StartButton" 
            Width="150" Height="40" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,20,10,0">Start</Button>
            <Button x:Name="StopButton" 
            Width="150" Height="40" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Margin="0,10,10,0">Stop</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```